# Unity, singleton : vector3 as field doesn't get passed while an int does

Tags: unity-game-engine, singleton, field

Disclaimer : I am a newbie in Unity and Csharp

I am working on some HexGrid game and I have defined as field properties of a simple Singleton class some vectors to use for computations (in that class).

Problem is the vectors are empty when I want to use them despite being initialized in the Awake() but I found out during debugging doing the same thing with an integer works fine.

Here is the code striped to the bare minimum to explain myself better :

```
 public class GridInterface : MonoBehaviour {
 private static GridInterface instance;

 Vector3 q1;
 int n;

 protected GridInterface() {}

 public static GridInterface Instance {
            get {
                    if (instance == null)
                            instance = GameObject.FindObjectOfType (typeof(GridInterface)) as GridInterface;
                    return instance;
            }
 }

    void Awake ()
    {

        Vector3 q1 = new Vector3(Mathf.Sqrt(3) * 0.5f, 0, -0.5f);
        n = 10;
        instance = this;              
    }

    void SomeFunction () {
        Debug.Log("n="+n);
        Debug.Log("q1="+q1);
    }
}
```

When I call `GridInterface.Instance.SomeFunction()`, I see as expected `n=10` but see `q1 = (0,0,0)`.

I guess I could use an array instead of a vector since I only need the coordinates but I would like to understand why the q1 value in the Awake isn't available when I work with the Instance.

How come ? What is special about Vector3 ?

edit : after some testing, it also happens with arrays, I don't think this is related to Unity, I must be missing something more basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like

```
 Vector3 q1 = ...
```

initializes a local variable but apparently you want to refer to the class member. Why don't you just refer to

```
 this.q1 = ...
```

just like you do with `n`?

Comment: Exactly this, you're making a new variable instead of instantiating the class member. I'm surprised the IDE isn't giving you a warning.